# Breadth First Search in Angularjs with async calls

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement BFS in angularjs where for each node you make a Restangular call. The 'while loop' should be run as many times as the number of nodes in the graph. But it runs only 1 time. As after making the async call(and without executing the part where we add children nodes in queue), JS engine goes forward in the loop and exits the loop as length of queue is zero.

How can we stop the execution till async call is completed? Should we poll on whether the async call has completed or not?

```
angular.module('app', ['restangular']);

angular.module('app')
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','Restangular', '$q',
  function($scope,Restangular,$q) 
  {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(0);


    //A set to track visited nodes
    var visited = {};

    while(queue.length != 0)
    {   
        var item = queue.shift();
        console.log("in while loop");

        //for each unvisited node, make a rest call to get it's children, then add them to queue and mark that node as visited
        if(!(item in visited)){
            defer.promise.then(Restangular.one('/some/path/getChildren',item).get().then(function()
            {
                //This part of code is executed only 1 time.
                console.log("made rest call for "+item);
                //each item can have 0 or 1 or 2 children
                queue.push(item.children);
                visited[item]=true;
            }
            ));
        }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Use concept of angular watch on queue array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in JS - the async call will get made *after* the function finishes. What you need to do is have a $q promise that you resolve *as soon as there are no items in the queue*. Your queue checking logic must be *within* the async callback - which may well need to reuse itself as callback for the next Restangular call.